# AngularJS not working..Not able to debug the error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

MY HTML PAGE

```
<head>
    <title>TODO supply a title</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <script src="assets/js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="HelloController">
        <h2>Hi {{helloTo.title}}, Start learning angular js</h2>

        Enter Your Name<input type="text" ng-model="name">
        <span ng-bind="name"></span>
    </div>
    <div ng-controller="studentController">

    </div>

</body>
```

ANd My JS

```
function HelloController($scope) {
$scope.helloTo = {};
$scope.helloTo.title = "Rahul Devan";
}
```

I need to use multiple controllers in the same page in a same JS file. That's why i have used controllers like this.

I am getting output like this
[image: Output I am getting]

Please help to figure out the error

Comment: Where you initialize your app ? Another thing is that you can not declare global controller functions on angular `>=1.3` versions. If you're not going to named your add, just use `ng-app` in that case. It's default directive of angular.

Comment: where is your ng-app directive?

Comment: `ng-app`  attribute should be defined with your module instance name.

Comment: Show error in console.

Comment: even if i use ng-app, how can i use multiple controllers..Sorry I am new to angularjs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey try this example to understand how to use multiple controllers for the same app module.

```js
var app = angular.module('sample', []);


app.controller('first', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'James';

});


app.controller('second', function($scope) {

  $scope.name = 'John';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="sample">
  <div ng-controller="first">First Controller:
    <span>{{name}}</span>
  </div>
  <div ng-controller="second">Second Controller:
    <span>{{name}}</span>
  </div>

</body>
```